# Why are extensions not available in @helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, extension-methods

I created a view extension like this:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public static class PageExtensions
    {
        public static HtmlString MyExt(this WebViewPage page)
        {
```

so I can now type in a Razor view:

```
@this.MyExt()
```

please note that my views all include the namespace where this is declared via the Web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="MyProject" />
```

everything good.  now I want to write a `@helper` function and use my extension there:

```
@helper MyHelper() {
    var page = (WebViewPage) CurrentPage;
    <div>
        @page.MyExt()
    </div>
}
```

but the extension is not available there.  the error I get is:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage' does not
>   contain a definition for 'MyExt' and no extension method
>   'MyExt' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

what am I missing?

Comment: `what am I missing?` maybe an assembly reference or a using directive?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the web.config which you modified is the "/Views/Web.Config"

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio requires a recompile of the project before it will recognize helpers you add to the view, and I suspect that is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was the namespace.  removing the namespace directive enclosing the PageExtensions class fixed it.  why that is? I'm not sure